# what's the other reasons causing fail to cancel the task?

Tags: java, multithreading, future

> "boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) Attempts to cancel
>   execution of this task. This attempt will fail if the task has already
>   completed, has already been cancelled, or could not be cancelled for
>   **some other reason**"

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)

Beside the reasons listed above, what's other reasons it would fail to cancel the task? 
Also if the task run the code like below can it be cancelled?

```
while(true)
{
;
}
```

Comment: There could be any number of reasons, but they all would fall under the category "the task doesn't stop despite your cancel request". Your while-true loop would be one of those many reasons.

Comment: @Erwin,Is there any rules\patterns for them?

Comment: also which types of task can be cancelled, any patterns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The while loop you post would be an example of non-cancelable code, since it does nothing to respond to interruption.

Code that blocks listening to a socket could also fail to handle interruption. Even if code timed out with an InterruptedIOException, if you swallow the exception without setting the interrupt flag then the code can fail to handle interruption.

So TLDR: 1) code that does blocking IO
2) code that is oblivious to how interruption works. Or a combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to terminate a thread in Java actually. You can basically tell a thread to stop, but the thread can be constantly waiting and never gets to read the flag or similar issues. It's actually a kind of complicated issue. So I assume instead of that they just said for "some issue".

Comment: is there any rules\patterns can be found which types of task can be cancelled, which cannot be?

Comment: The recommended way is to check for a flag periodically inside the thread. Thats really up to how you actually do a task. This obviously goes only for Threads which might run forever or for a long time. In other cases its just better to let the thread run and deal with it once you get your result. Typical case when your context got destoyed but you just returned from a thread.

Answer (score 0):

Each thread has a special flag that holds the interruption state, it's accessible by means of `isInterrupted()` method. When someone interrupts a thread, this flag is set to `true`. That's all. No real interruption happens until the code, executed by this thread, checks this flag and either throws an `InterruptedException` or just quits the thread execution if it can.

Many methods in the standard library, that are designed to block the current thread, actually check this flag from time to time and throw an `InterruptedException` when they found the flag is set. For instance, `Thread.sleep()`, `Thread.join()`, `Object.wait()`, `Lock.lockInterruptibly()` and many others. Hence, when your thread periodically checks this flag explicitly or is blocked by some of the described methods that check it implicitly, it's interruptable. Otherwise, it's not.

So, the thread with an empty loop cannot be interrupted because it doesn't check the interruption status. But adding an interruption state check would fix it:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) { }
```

Calling a method responsive to interruptions would also work:

```
try {
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(timeout);
    }
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
    // Do nothing, just let the thread exit
}
```